# Install / Unistall from shell command in Android

Tags: android, silent-installer

I want to implement a silent installer-from-apk-file and unistaller-package in Android.
The topic has largely been discussed on SO and elsewhere but I can't apply any for some reason that I'm missing.
The scope is obviously hard to achieve because, if successful, it would be a serious security breach in Android. BUT, I need to implement it for a special project, not for the consumer market.
There are two approaches:

1. to generate a custom ROM from a source code (AOSP or Cyanogen mod, for example), by tweaking the PackageManager installer (in fact just to remove the user acceptance dialog boxes).
2. to do it programmatically by creating a process as super user and executing an 'adb shell pm install'. I previously installed 'su' in /system/xbin and I test during run time that RootTools.rootIsAvailable().

For the first case, I digged into the Froyo source code but got into a dead end with a @hide marked method.
For the second I've first tried the commands from the terminal

```
adb shell pm install /mnt/sdcard/HelloAndroid.apk
```

and

```
adb shell pm uninstall com.example.helloandroid
```

Both work OK. Then, I used the following code, the development being tested on a rooted emulator (2.2 - Froyo):

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId())
           {
              case R.id.btnInstall:
                  try {  
                      install = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su\n");   
                      DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(install.getOutputStream());
                      os.writeBytes("pm install /mnt/sdcard/HelloAndroid.apk\n"); 
                      os.writeBytes("exit\n"); 
                      os.flush();
                      install.waitFor();

                              if (install.exitValue() == 0) {  
                                  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                              }  
                              else {  
                                  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failure. Exit code: "+String.valueOf(install.exitValue()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                              }
                  }
                  catch (InterruptedException e) {  
                      logError(e);
                  }
                  catch (IOException e) {  
                  logError(e);
                  } 
                  break;

              case R.id.btnUninstall:
                  try {
                      install = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su\n"); 
                      install=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pm uninstall "+txtPackageName.getText().toString()+"\n");

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logError(e);
                }
                  break;
           }

    }
```

To avoid typos and other trims I hardcoded the apk file parameter of the command for the installation; on 'case R.id.btnInstall' the command is not executed and the exit is on "Failure" with exit value 1, meaning that "the class cannot be found"; no clue what that means ...
I appreciate your help!

EDITED: I have the clean solution, I shall post the answer from A-Z as soon as I have the time and the code in the right form!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I promised here is the solution to this problem, without doing any forcing to the system other than having to install the whole application in the /system/app directory. I have followed, then did some fixing to the excellent article here: http://paulononaka.wordpress.com/2011/07/02/how-to-install-a-application-in-background-on-android/. I have downloaded the zip file referenced in the article then, (I tried to keep the same class names where possible):

1. created a new project and a main activity as entry point

```
package com.example.silentinstuninst;

import java.io.File;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

import com.example.instuninsthelper.ApplicationManager;
import com.example.instuninsthelper.OnDeletedPackage;
import com.example.instuninsthelper.OnInstalledPackage;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Process install;
    Button btnInstall, btnUninstall;
    EditText txtApkFileName, txtPackageName; 

    public static final String TAG = "SilentInstall/Uninstall";

    private static ApplicationManager am;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initializeValues();

    }

    private void initializeValues() {

        btnInstall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnInstall);
        btnUninstall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUninstall);
        txtApkFileName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtApkFilePath);
        txtPackageName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPackageName);

        btnInstall.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnUninstall.setOnClickListener(this);

        try {
            am = new ApplicationManager(this);
            am.setOnInstalledPackage(new OnInstalledPackage() {

                public void packageInstalled(String packageName, int returnCode) {
                    if (returnCode == ApplicationManager.INSTALL_SUCCEEDED) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Install succeeded");
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Install failed: " + returnCode);
                    }
                }
            });

            am.setOnDeletedPackage(new OnDeletedPackage() {
                public void packageDeleted(boolean succeeded) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Uninstall succeeded");  
                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logError(e);
        }
    }

    private void logError(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.error+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId())
           {
              case R.id.btnInstall:
                  // InstallUninstall.Install(txtApkFileName.getText().toString());
            try {
                am.installPackage(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
                        File.separator + txtApkFileName.getText().toString());
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } // install package
                  break;

              case R.id.btnUninstall:
                  // InstallUninstall.Uninstall(txtPackageName.getText().toString());
            try {
                am.uninstallPackage(txtPackageName.getText().toString());
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                logError(e);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                logError(e);
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                logError(e);
            }
                  break;
           }    
    }
}
```

2. create in /src the package *com.example.instuninsthelper*. I have added there the ApplicationManager.java and OnInstalledPackage.java files
3. inserted the following code inside the ApplicationManager class:

```
private OnDeletedPackage onDeletedPackage;
class PackageDeleteObserver extends IPackageDeleteObserver.Stub { 

        public void packageDeleted(boolean succeeded) throws RemoteException {
            if (onDeletedPackage != null) {
                onDeletedPackage.packageDeleted(succeeded);
            }
        }

    }
```

4. created, under the same *com.example.instuninsthelper* package the file OnDeletedPackage.java with the following code:

```
package com.example.instuninsthelper;
public interface OnDeletedPackage {
    public void packageDeleted(boolean succeeded);
}
```

5. in the android.content.pm package (the namespace SHOULD not be changed) I modified the IPackageDeleteObserver.java, with this result:

```
package android.content.pm;

public interface IPackageDeleteObserver extends android.os.IInterface {

    public abstract static class Stub extends android.os.Binder implements android.content.pm.IPackageDeleteObserver {
        public Stub() {
            throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
        }

        public static android.content.pm.IPackageDeleteObserver asInterface(android.os.IBinder obj) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
        }

        public android.os.IBinder asBinder() {
            throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
        }

        public boolean onTransact(int code, android.os.Parcel data, android.os.Parcel reply, int flags)
                throws android.os.RemoteException {
            throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
        }
    }

    public abstract void packageDeleted(boolean succeeded)
            throws android.os.RemoteException;
}
```

6. build the application in Eclipse and deploy it to the emulator
7. in the emulator: home button > Settings > applications > ...uninstall the application (because it is not installed in /system/app, and we just needed the generation of the apk file)
8. do the following to root the emulator (so that we can write in /system/app; other solution, that I have used, is to generate a custom ROM with this app included into the /system/app):

   - download the su file from here http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=682828http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=682828. Rename it to su.zip
   - then from the console:
         * adb shell mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock03 /system
         * adb push su.zip /system/xbin/su
         * adb shell chmod 06755 /system
         * adb shell chmod 06755 /system/xbin/su
9. from the console, go to the /bin directory of the project, then enter:
           * adb push .apk  /system/app
10. finally, always from the console, enter:
            * adb shell am start -n com.example.silentinstuninst/com.example.silentinstuninst.MainActivity
11. enjoy!

Comment: when you do a mount does it allow you to mount? Is your device rw permitted..in other words in your default.prop file is your value rosecure =0 instead of 1? When I try to run remount command it fails silently the ro  permissions are not changed to rw permission. Pls help.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know, but just a idea:

I think that you are writing in the standarout, not executing a command nor giving extra data to the process via its input. I think it should be:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pm install /mnt/sdcard/HelloAndroid.apk\n");
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Installing in the `/system/app` directory is essentially the same as requiring root.

Assuming you have root, check out [RootTools](http://code.google.com/p/roottools/). Then you can do:

```
if (RootTools.isAccessGiven()) {
    CommandCapture command = new CommandCapture(0, "pm install " + PATH_TO_APK);
    RootTools.getShell(true).add(command).waitForFinish();
}
```

Note that `waitForFinish()` is a blocking call!

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do this also with the PackageManager directly (requires root access):

- Create an app with a platform-sdk which has the interfaces publicly (create or download it, and configure eclipse)
- In the app directly call the hidden API functions which allow silent install/remove.
- Install the APK on your device as a system app by copying it to /system/app (root needed)

See this: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1711653

Comment: I'm sorry but it seems I'm not at your knowledge level: I don't understand 'has the interfaces publicly'. What you propose is exactly as per this post: http://paulononaka.wordpress.com/2011/07/02/how-to-install-a-application-in-background-on-android/. Only that I've run his example and it fails (seems to be a signature problem). I'd appreciate if you can get into details. Why the code above is wrong? What means the 'class not found' error?

Comment: The blog is talking about something else.

Comment: Thanks RvdK, I found the solution and explain it soon. It is based on the principles of that post, sorry for not being clear

Answer (score 0):

> Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pm install /mnt/sdcard/HelloAndroid.apk\n");

This works for me, although two more additional details have to be done:

1. Add  **android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"** in AndroidManifest.xml.
2. Signed the apk with the system key.

   But in this way it seems there is no way to tell whether the installation is succeeded, so I will try @Ginger's method later.

Answer (score 0):

For all who are still having problem: you will need a rooted device and use

```
Process result = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pm install -r -d MyApp.apk /system/app")
```

If you are getting result code 9 (error code 9) you will need to delete your apk from the device and push it back (PUSH not INSTAL!).

Go to the device shell and Push the apk

```
launcher=MyApp.apk
$adb shell su -c "mount -o remount,rw -t rfs /dev/stl5 /system"
$adb push $launcher /sdcard/$launcher
$adb shell su -c "chmod 644 /system/app/$launcher"
```

Now you are able to use pm install without getting an error. Hope it will help somebody.

Comment: Can you explain what is going on here?