# Code to customize the android apk installer dialog screen

Tags: android, apk, android-install-apk

When I write code to update my android application using

`"application/vnd.android.package-archive"`

it always ask for conformation with a dialog window, but when I update the same APK to the play store, there is no dialog screen appears.

How I can avoid or customize the android APK installer dialog screen?

Comment: if you are an application developer you may be able do same if you have root access. Google play/Google play services are not regular apps they are system apps or I should say privileged system apps.

Comment: but how google is doing with our rooting??

Comment: oky You need to understand system-apps have access to special permissions & they can execute as 'system' user who is one level below root and has access to most of the internal api which is not available to normal apps

Comment: so can i able to update android app in background as google is doing

Comment: unless you have root access or you are able to push you app as system apps

Comment: ok let us consider i have root access, then how i can do it?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14871570/install-unistall-from-shell-command-in-android

Comment: oky, thank you so much for your response