# How to hide/unhide app without root device 5.0 +

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-security, android-applicationinfo

I make application that **hide other apps**. I **succeed to hide and unhide other app**s **with rooted device**. But when i was trying on unrooted device, not succeeded. I also tried with nfs, Device owner but not getting success. Followed these links. tried with manage permission also but not working. Please help me if anyone getting success without rooted device.

**Error: root require:**

```
 E/hide: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: attempt to change component state from pid=23999, uid=10263, package uid=10264
```

**followed these links below:**

http://www.eoeandroid.com/thread-288229-1-1.html [Install / Unistall from shell command in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14871570/install-unistall-from-shell-command-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You have to take device owner in order to use the hide/unhide api. You can use [this guide to understand about the device owner](http://florent-dupont.blogspot.ca/2015/02/10-things-to-know-about-device-owner.html)

Once you have achieved device owner, you can use the following apis: [`setApplicationHidden`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#setApplicationHidden(android.content.ComponentName,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean)).

Comment: Please refrain from posting linkys that would suffer from link rot. Give a summary, on it, this is a linky only answer.